# How to change NLog target's connection string at runtime?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api, nlog

In my WebAPI application I am trying to make logging into several separate databases in `Application_BeginRequest` based on my custom header value.

To accomplish that I tried to modify `target` in `Nlog.config` like so:

```
<target name="database" 
        xsi:type="Database" 
        connectionString="${gdc:item=myConnectionstring}" 
        commandText="..sql command..">..params..</target>
```

and in `Application_BeginRequest` I tried to set that `myConnectionstring` like so:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myConnectionString", connectionString);
```

But that doesn't work and in NLog's `internalLogFile` error shown up:

```
2015-02-19 12:12:48.8776 Error Error when writing to database System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.OpenConnection(String connectionString)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteEventToDatabase(LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
```

I tried to write into db (with constant connection string configuration) following parameters:

```
<parameter name="@cn" layout="${gdc:myConnectionstring}"/>
<parameter name="@cn1" layout="${gdc:item=myConnectionstring}"/>
```

But they appeared to be empty, however when I debug my WebApi Action that throws error that I expect to be written in database, `GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Get("myConnectionString")` returns expected value.

What I am doing wrong? Why I can see expected value in `GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Get("myConnectionString")` but `${gdc:item=myConnectionstring}` resolves to empty string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found an alternative way to accomplish that:

```
var databaseTarget = (DatabaseTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("database");
databaseTarget.ConnectionString = connectionString;
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

However still not clear why `GlobalDiagnosticsContext` stuff is not working..

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for solution!

Still, if you want to use asynchronous database target, you will need to get wrapped target first:

```cs
DatabaseTarget databaseTarget;
var target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("database");
if (target is AsyncTargetWrapper)
    databaseTarget = (target as AsyncTargetWrapper).WrappedTarget as DatabaseTarget;
else
    databaseTarget = target as DatabaseTarget;
if (databaseTarget == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("Can't find DatabaseTarget with name 'database'");

databaseTarget.ConnectionString = connectionStringSelected.ConnectionString;
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```